# Images stored on google drive are not loading on a website hosted on heroku

Tags: html, image, heroku, google-drive-api

I have put some images on a small web app but they are not opening. I can only see the image box but not the image, but when I use right click and open the image in other tabs, the image opens.

- Images stored on Google Drive.
- Server is Heroku
- Created using Otree
  The following is the code.

`<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=--code--" width="600px"></div>`

This used to work without a problem but suddenly stopped working.

I tried reducing the image size, and security settings of my browser but the problem still exists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We're going to need more details. _Specifically,_ what does "but they are not opening" mean? Are you getting a 404? 401 or 403? Is this specific to Heroku (unlikely) or do the URLs fail to load if you visit them manually?

Comment: Google drive is not a file server

Comment: I have followed otree documents as these are static files, 

https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html?highlight=images#images-static-files

Comment: I also tried Dropbox and imgur

Comment: Dropbox _also_ isn't a file server...